# Initializing static variables in a function rather than at beginning of file

Tags: c++, opengl, static

I'm quite new to C++ and have stumbled across following problem: I have a struct with all-static members which loads models to VAOs and VBOs(OpenGL). I want to create a constant static object which stores the information needed to render a VAO(Note: the constant is not the issue here). The problem here is that I have to wait for an OpenGL context to be created and can only call the loading function afterwards (My idea was an `init()` function), but all static variables have to be declared directly! (I have also tried creating struct with non-static members and just creating a static instantiation of that struct but the model still has to be defined in the constructor). Any help would be great!

EDIT: I have also realized that C++ probably wants to avoid this altogether so I shouldn't be trying to find a loophole. I'm just seeking for a solution which could also involve completely restructuring what I've done so far.

Comment: The issue is not the `const` declaration, I've removed that modifier but it still doesn't work. It doesn't really matter to me wether it's constant or not. But thanks for the link, very interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several ways to do

- to not have a static struct but a static pointer to the struct, and to allocate it when you have the context to initialize it (*S1 * G1* in my example below)
- to update the struct when you have the context to do (*S2 G2* in the example below)

Example :

```
#include <iostream>

struct S1 {
  S1(int v) : _v(v) {}
  int _v;
};

struct S2 {
  int _v;

  void set(int v) { _v = v; }
};

const S1 * G1;
S2 G2;

int main()
{
  int v;

  std::cin >> v;

  // now we are able to set the structs

  G1 = new S1(v);
  G2.set(v); // note G2._c is public and can be set directly too

  // etc
}
```

Comment: This is really good but I'm creating this static pointer in a separate method than the rendering one which would mean that the data I deleted at the end of `init()` right?

Comment: It worked! Although I thought `Constants* pointer = new Constants();` would delete the Constants object it points to at the end of the method. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @J.Lengel I am not sure to understand you. You can mix the two solutions having `S * G;` and somewhere `G = new S;` and somewhere after `G->init();` to initialize some members not yet initialized when you constructed it

Comment: _would delete the Constants object it points to at the end of the method._ why ? in the form `Constants* pointer = new Constants();` the destructor is not called

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I was wondering. Good to know!